# Maven plugin execution not covered - again

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I am getting kind of frustrated with this issue. I have this plugin inside my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
     <goals>
      <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
     </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  ...
```

And I am getting always this eclipse message **plugin configuration not covered by maven lifecycle**

This error is getting anoying. I found out that if i move this one into pluginConfiguration the error is gone, but that is due it isn't called anymore because its for inheritance maven structures.

If I remove the execution elements, eclipse is happy again, but it is not called anymore.

So I tried to add this huge plugin configuration (lifecycle-mapping) where I have no idea what it is about, but it didn't help at all:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
   <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0</version>
   <configuration>
      <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          <pluginExecutions>
              <pluginExecution>
                   <pluginExecutionFilter>
                       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                       <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                       <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                       <goals>
                          <goal>test-compile</goal>
                          <goal>compile</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </pluginExecutionFilter>
                   <action>
                       <execute />
                   </action>
               </pluginExecution>
           </pluginExecutions>
       </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I was able to build this project inside eclipse without errors, but it always displays the execution tag as error and during importing existing maven project I get also an error.

I deleted the error in eclipse :-) That worked fine, but next time the error will appear again. If I google that issue I will find so many topics about that so why is that not fixed yet?

I also read this article
http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered
but hornestly if that is the solution I think maven and eclipse don't fit together.

What I also don't get, why do I have to tell maven when to execute this plugin? I don't need to tell maven on each plugin when to execute. Why on this one? Can I configure that in a different way?

Thanks for help and many greetings,
Hauke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include "phase":

```
<execution>
<phase>package</phase>
 <goals>
  <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
 </goals>
</execution>
```

Comment: Wow that works. I don't get why this is working, but it does. Do I tell maven to run the goal wsdl2java when the phase "package" is running? If I don't use phase, what is the default? Or does that depends on the plugin and now we override the default from the plugin?

Comment: Yes, you tell run plugin on "package" phase, but looks for this plugin better use other phase "generate-sources", better look on plugin documentation. Some plugins don't have default phase, and also you can override default phase.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the error `not covered by life cycle...` you have to use the same plugin name as you really like to use in your build:

```xml
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
          <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
              <pluginExecutions>
                <pluginExecution>
                  <pluginExecutionFilter>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                    <goals>
                      <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                  </pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <action>
                    <execute />
                  </action>
                </pluginExecution>
              </pluginExecutions>
            </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Apart from that i would suggest to use an up-to-date version of the [axistools-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/)
The reason why you have to configure this plugin is simple. Cause it's not in the life-cyclce by default. You have to bind it to the lifecylce. In this case the plugin has a [default binding](http://mojo.codehaus.org/axistools-maven-plugin/wsdl2java-mojo.html) which will be active you give it in the pom like the above. Otherwise you have had it doing it by explicitly given that:

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

You can if you like or need configure the axistools-plugin to your needs.